# How to extract all urls from a web page containing "show more" with Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm quite new in webscraping field, I previously used a code to extract urls from website containing multiple pages and then save them in a txt file. I would like to apply it to a new website but which has only a single page but with a "show more" button.

Here is the webpage :
http://sdg.iisd.org/news/

And here is my code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd 



links = []

for i in range(#221):
    url = 'http://sdg.iisd.org/news/'  #+ str(i) <-- for webpage with many pages

    response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

    if response.ok:
        print('Page: ' + str(i))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
        div = soup.findAll('article')
        for article in div:
            a = article.find('a')
            link = a['href']
            links.append('https://sdg.iisd.org/news' + link)

        print(len(links))

with open('urls.txt', 'w') as file:
    for link in links:
        file.write(link + '\n')
```

Some people suggest to use Selenium but I couldn't find example of a similar application that I have. Do you have any idea of what I could use and change in my code to obtain all links of the page ?

Comment: DevTools shows that clicking on "Show More" initiates a POST to `http://sdg.iisd.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` with, among others, the parameter `pageNumber=2`. See your DevTools for the other parameters and request headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you log your browser's network traffic, you can see that pressing the `Show more` button makes an XHR Request to `http://sdg.iisd.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` via HTTP POST, and the response is HTML. You can copy the POST payload from your browser's dev tools as well. Play around with the `pageNumber` and `ppp` key-value pairs in the `data` payload dictionary to get different articles:

```
def main():
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
    from operator import itemgetter

    url = "http://sdg.iisd.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

    data = {
        "template": "load_more",
        "post_type": "news",
        "sdgs": "",
        "issues": "",
        "globalpartnership": "",
        "actors": "",
        "actions": "",
        "regions": "",
        "behaviour": "exact",
        "sort_by": "DESC",
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "ppp": "12",
        "action": "more_post_ajax",
        "author": ""
    }

    response = requests.post(url, data=data)
    response.raise_for_status()

    soup = Soup(response.content, "html.parser")

    article_urls = list(map(itemgetter("href"), soup.select("article > a")))
    print(article_urls)
    
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
['http://sdg.iisd.org/news/wef-event-explores-ways-to-fix-international-trade-system/', 'http://sdg.iisd.org/news/wto-members-resume-negotiations-on-fisheries-subsidies/', 'http://sdg.iisd.org/news/informal-ministerial-highlights-role-of-trade-in-promoting-covid-19-recovery/', 'http://sdg.iisd.org/news/wto-imf-project-uneven-covid-19-recovery-across-and-within-countries/', 'http://sdg.iisd.org/news/53-wto-members-commit-to-ease-restrictions-on-humanitarian-food-aid/', 'http://sdg.iisd.org/news/development-goals-can-work-even-amid-crisis-but-we-need-to-measure-better/', 'http://sdg.iisd.org/news/unctad-partners-launch-tool-to-identify-exchange-traded-funds-with-sdg-alignment/', 'http://sdg.iisd.org/news/tool-helps-measure-quality-of-stakeholder-engagement-in-sdgs/', 'http://sdg.iisd.org/news/unctad-reveals-economic-slowdown-before-covid-19-provides-key-data-on-rcep-agreement/', 'http://sdg.iisd.org/news/unep-report-identifies-top-actions-to-minimize-adverse-impacts-of-pesticides-fertilizers/', 'http://sdg.iisd.org/news/regions-to-hold-sustainable-development-forums-ahead-of-2021-hlpf/', 'http://sdg.iisd.org/news/ndc-partnership-reflects-on-milestone-year-for-climate-ambition/']
>>>
```